# How to log an http header along with other data in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, logback

I have a REST spring mvc application where, inside of my controllers, I (of course) have logs.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
Collection<Bookmark> readBookmarks(@PathVariable String userId) {
    this.validateUser(userId);
    LOG.info("user successfully validated");
    return this.bookmarkRepository.findByAccountUsername(userId);
}
```

My pattern in logback would be something like this:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
```

Each GET method is an http request, with several headers. 
Would it be possible to alter the above logback pattern to also add the contents of a specific header MY_HEADER?
Something like:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}|%HTTP_HEADER(MY_HEADER)| [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
```

After all each controller method has an underlying HttpRequest the framework masks. I think it should be possible, right? And how to do that transparently so to not alter my java code? I want to still only log the message and leave to the underlying framework the task of adding that http header.

Comment: spring boot has an actuator ```/trace``` to log all recent requests and if you want it through configuration then there is already an interceptor ```org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter``` just enable it in spring-boot properties file ```org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter``` to DEBUG

Comment: Ok but that would just add one more log line: I need to add an information to my existing ones..